# CORS for httaccess to web.config

Tags: iis, cors, plesk

how do I convert this htaccess codes to webconfig?

My wordpress site ultilize a REST api: "wp-json". The configuration for cross-origin resources sharing are configured in a way that any website is able to make request to the rest api. So I have to disallow. I found out that in htaccess, it should look something like this.

```
<Directory "/path/to/wp-json">
   <IfModule mod_headers.c>
 Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
   </IfModule>
</Directory>
```

But how do I do it for plesk hosting, web.config?

Comment: IIS has a dedicate module, https://blogs.iis.net/iisteam/introducing-iis-cors-1-0

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you want to do is simply add a response header of Access-Control-Allow-Origin:* to any request that goes to http://hostname/path/to/wp-json/.  The following should do that.

```
Add-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/Default Web Site' -location 'path/to/wp-json' -filter "system.webServer/httpProtocol/customHeaders" -name "." -value @{name='Access-Control-Allow-Origin';value='*'}
```

Comment: I am new to this IIS.

Comment: <configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
   
   <rule name="ignore web forms folder wpjson" stopProcessing="true">
     <match url="^wpjson/" />
     <action type="None" />
   </rule>
The codes are written like these and i do not know how to put yours in

Comment: My code was a PowerShell script which would make a modification the Web.config under your Default Web Site.

Comment: How do I even use powershell script? Sorry i've been using linux server and .htaccess all these while.

Comment: You'd launch Powershell.exe from the StartMenu or from a command prompt and then past in that line above.  You may have also do Import-Module WebAdministration.